# seperating a list of numbers

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a `.txt` file with a large amount of numbers that goes like this:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 11 11 
11 12 12 12 12 13 15 15 15 15 15
```

The raw data is unbroken line with all values separated by a single space. I would like to use this as data in R and do some computations on them. How can I manipulate the data so that R sees each of them as a separate value?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the original text data? The solution really depends on the data's actual format. For example, is the raw data really one unbroken line (no newline characters) with all values separated by a single space, or are these tabs? There is not enough information in what you have provided.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I do not know how to give the sample, but yes, your first guess is true. This is just thousands of numbers with one unbroken line, each number seperated by a single space.

Comment: You probably want `scan(file = "myfile.txt", quiet = TRUE)` which will read the values into a vector.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try:

```
nums = as.numeric(strsplit(readLines("nums.txt")," ")[[1]])
```

Or:

```
matrix(read.table("nums.txt"))
```

Comment: They didn't work!

Comment: well i would the scan approach that was mentioned in the comments, but without access to your file, it would be hard to help further

Comment: How can I share my file with you?

Comment: `pwd()` & `list.files()`, is your '.txt' there or is it `my_many_nums <- scan('~/dir_where_it_is/number_space.txt', quiet = TRUE)`?